# In dom structure are attributes child nodes or siblings?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have an paragraph element  with a title attribute. Since everything in DOM structure is a node, what is the relationship between p and title attribute ? Are they siblings or is the title attribute a child node of `<p>` or a sibling ? And can I access the content of title attribute using nodeValue property ?

Comment: Attributes are **not** nodes, but actually attributes of the node.

Comment: So what qualifies as nodes in dom structure ?

Comment: The **tags**, not their attributes.

Comment: @Esailija: could you please clarify that? Also, that does it mean that "I am upvoted"?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari you said attributes are not nodes, that's not correct

Comment: @Esailija Could be, but no need to be rude anyway.

Comment: For what it is worth, Esailija was probably not being rude, just to the point. He said you were not correct and noted that the upvotes on your comment were unjust as the comment was false. I don't see this as 'rude', rather less sugar coated than some might like.

Comment: @DevlshOne see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18103052/829835), your last comment is also false.

Comment: This started a conversation in the [javascript room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), if you're interested: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11113986#11113986

Comment: @DevlshOne where he's right he's right. Comment Sergeant Octavian out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The element that has the attribute node is the `.ownerElement` of the attribute node. There is no tree-like relationships otherwise - the siblings, parentNode etc of an attribute node are empty.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-637646024

> Attr objects inherit the Node interface, but since they are not
>   actually child nodes of the element they describe, the DOM does not
>   consider them part of the document tree. Thus, the Node attributes
>   parentNode, previousSibling, and nextSibling have a null value for
>   Attr objects.

The relationship is:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.title = "hello";

var titleAttr = p.attributes.title //from the element to the attribute

p = titleAttr.ownerElement //from the attribute node to the owning element
```

> And can I access the content of title attribute using nodeValue property

If you have an attribute node, you can access the key/name with:

```
titleAttr.nodeName; //"title"
```

You can access the value with:

```
titleAttr.nodeValue; //"hello"
```

Also the `.nodeType` is `2` or `Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. So attributes are nodes but they aren't part of the dom tree. I have come across some diagrams on w3schools where attributes have been represented as part of dom tree.

Comment: I have come across that site and heard bad things about w3schools but lately I've come across books and video tutorials (from lynda) that have used w3schools as a reference !